# why laravel overwrite two different veribales in query?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using this query to get 2 different results in `$week_expence` and `$month_expence`

```
 $week = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(7);
 $month = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(30);
 
 $expences =  SellerSell::where(['seller_id' => $id , 'order_confirmed_by' => $id ]);
 $week_expence = $expences->where('created_at','>=',$week)->sum('expenses');
 $month_expence = $expences->where('created_at','>=',$month)->sum('expenses');
 dd($week_expence , $month_expence);
```

Consider if `$week_expence` = 10 and `$month_expence` = 20 then I get result in both veriables week and month is 10. Why I am getting week expence in month?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Laravel query builder is a mutable object meaning each time you add a `where` it changes the query builder itself and returns a reference to it so when you call `$expences->where('created_at','>=',$week)` it actually modifies the `$expences` instance.

Here's how you can solve this with less code duplication:

```
 $week = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(7);
 $month = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(30);
 
 $expences =  SellerSell::where(['seller_id' => $id , 'order_confirmed_by' => $id ]);  
 $week_expence = (clone $expences)->where('created_at','>=',$week)->sum('expenses');

 $month_expence = (clone $expences)->where('created_at','>=',$month)->sum('expenses');
 dd($week_expence , $month_expence);
```

This will ensure the instance is copied instead of the original one mutated.

Comment: i am very thankfull to you this thing is very helpful for me thanx for your contribution

Answer (score 2):

You can't use one query for two different things.

```
$week = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(7);
$month = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(30);
 
$week_expence =  SellerSell::where([
    'seller_id' => $id ,
    'order_confirmed_by' => $id
])
    ->where('created_at','>=',$week)
    ->sum('expenses');
$month_expence = SellerSell::where([
    'seller_id' => $id ,
    'order_confirmed_by' => $id
])
    ->where('created_at','>=',$month)
    ->sum('expenses');
dd($week_expence , $month_expence);
```

Of course, you don't need to have duplicate code and that's where [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes) come in handy:

```
class SellerSell extends Model
{
    public function scopeExpense($query, \Carbon\Carbon $date)
    {
        return $query->where([
            'seller_id' => $id,
            'order_confirmed_by' => $id
        ])
            ->where('created_at','>=',$date);
    }
}
```

```
$week = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(7);
$month = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(30);
 
$week_expence =  SellerSell::expense($week)->sum('expenses');
$month_expence = SellerSell::expense($month)->sum('expenses');
dd($week_expence , $month_expence);
```